# org.apache.xml.security.encryption.XMLEncryptionException: Illegal key size or default parameters

Tags: spring, spring-ws

**Hi when i am trying to add securement Encryption Sym Algorithm in spring ws configuration it is giving following exception** :

```
Caused by: org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: Cannot encrypt data; nested exception is: 
    org.apache.xml.security.encryption.XMLEncryptionException: Illegal key size or default parameters
Original Exception was java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size or default parameters
    at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecEncrypt.doEncryption(WSSecEncrypt.java:599)
    at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecEncrypt.doEncryption(WSSecEncrypt.java:459)
    at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecEncrypt.encryptForInternalRef(WSSecEncrypt.java:348)
    at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecEncrypt.build(WSSecEncrypt.java:309)
    at org.apache.ws.security.action.EncryptionAction.execute(EncryptionAction.java:62)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.xml.security.encryption.XMLEncryptionException: Illegal key size or default parameters
Original Exception was java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size or default parameters
    at org.apache.xml.security.encryption.XMLCipher.encryptData(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xml.security.encryption.XMLCipher.encryptData(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xml.security.encryption.XMLCipher.encryptElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xml.security.encryption.XMLCipher.doFinal(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecEncrypt.doEncryption(WSSecEncrypt.java:593)
    ... 24 more
```

Comment: Can anybody help me out where I am missing.
My WSS4jSecurityInspector Configuration is as follows :   <property name="securementEncryptionSymAlgorithm" value="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc" />

Comment: Issue resolved after updating JRE with stated packge: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-6-download-429243.html       :) :)

Answer (score 2):

Does this help?: http://blog.rampartfaq.com/2009/08/faq-001-javasecurityinvalidkeyexception.html

> You need to patch your JDK with Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files.

Answer (score 1):

After Updating the JDK library with "Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 6" the problem was resolved.

you can download library from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-6-download-429243.html

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty old question(Links in the answers are either not working or does not provide details for latest java versions).

I faced the issue recently and would like to add more details.

**Root Cause:**
Java 8 and earlier versions does not support keys with 256-bit AES encryption by default; only 128-bit AES encryption is supported.

**Solution:**
Issue can be resolved by installing the Oracle Java JCE unlimited strength jars. Follow the link to download the jars for Java 8 and earlier versions: [Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-all-download-5170447.html).

Jar files are available for Java versions 6, 7 and 8.

Download the zip file by accepting license agreement, unzip it and copy these jar files to **$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/** directory. Restart application, if running already, for the jars to take effect.

Java 9 and later uses the unlimited policy files by default.